# Declare different variables according to property value

Tags: c#, variable-declaration

I would like to know how can I create different variables according to the value of a property.

Example:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in entry.Columns)
{
    if(column.ColumnName.Contains("weight") || 
       column.ColumnName.Contains("amount"))
        float column.ColumnName = 0;
}
```

In this case the code would create as much variables as columns in entry contains the selected words and the variables would be called as the columnName property.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achive with that?

Comment: Why won't a collection be sufficient? You can just use a Dictionary and access the values by key.

Comment: These could be done by Array, List, Dictionary which could be used but depends on what you need to store

Comment: You can't declare local variables on the fly. This needs more context as to what you are doing, but I *suspect* your best bet is a `Dictionary<string,object>` (as a name/value store). What ***exactly*** are you trying to do? This may impact the answer.

Comment: Actually I thought about it trying to get something which I resolved a different way but I wanted to know if it was possible in anyway.

Comment: Marc Gravell, I think your comment would be the fair answer for being earlier and exactly the same than Anton Kedrov (was registered several minutes ago). So if you write it like an answer I will select it like the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for that purpose could be used Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, float> columnNameAndValue = new Dictionary<string, float>();

foreach (DataColumn column in entry.Columns)
{
    if (column.ColumnName.Contains("weight") || 
        column.ColumnName.Contains("amount")) //float column.ColumnName = 0;
    {
        columnNameAndValue.Add(column.ColumnName, 0);
    }
}
```